# Not changing focus when calling setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Tags: android, focus, visibility

I have a scenario where when an action occurs I want to make certain fields visible. This works fine, however when I call setVisible(View.VISIBLE) on a LinearLayout that contains a few other fields, such as a TextEdit, the focus shifts to the TextEdit (or at least the screen scrolls to it).

Is there a way to not have the focus change when calling setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)?

The XML layout of the LinearLayout I can calling setVisible on:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="" />

     <EditText android:id="@+id/entry"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="right" /> 

    <View
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code that initializes it:

```
private TextView mName;
private EditText mEntry;
```

...

```
     private void initialize() {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.field_multiline_entry, this);

        // setup fields
        mName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        mEntry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry);
        mEntry.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    }
```

And the code that is calling the setVisibility:

```
        if(sectionFieldView != null && sectionFieldView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) 
        {
            sectionFieldView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to my friend below, the following code works. It basically makes all the descendants of the LinearLayout unable to gain focus, which means when made visible the screen does not scroll to them as they do not gain focus. Only way to date I have found to keep this from happening...

```
        ((ViewGroup) fieldView).setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        fieldView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((ViewGroup) fieldView).setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
```

Comment: Try setting `editText.setFocusable(false)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might try the `android:descendantFocusability` with `beforeDescendants` parameter on your LinearLayout?

```
Constant    Value   Description
beforeDescendants   0   The ViewGroup will get focus before any of its descendants.
afterDescendants    1   The ViewGroup will get focus only if none of its descendants want it.
blocksDescendants   2   The ViewGroup will block its descendants from receiving focus.
```

Comment: This needs to happen at runtime...basically I need to make the contents of the LinearLayout visible but don't want the descendants to get visibility. Doesn't seem to be a method on the View.

Comment: Wow! It actually worked...thanks! I have to do the following though:     ((ViewGroup) fieldView).setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    fieldView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((ViewGroup) fieldView).setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);

Comment: I think you can set the parameter I wrote above in your .xml file and it should work fine. Just add 'android:descendantFocusability = "blocksDescendants"

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't sure if it would completely block focus - which I do not want to do. I want to "turn off" the focus momentarily till my visibility operations are done and turn it back on. The code above works perfectly. Thank you very much for the help!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for your comment @StephenMcCormick
Updating the descendantFocusability at runtime solved the same issue for me too!

Answer (score 0):

I found out changing View.INVISIBLE to View.VISIBLE doesn't cause the focus to be changed.